Mind maps not letting me have more than 6 siblings
I am trying to make a mindmap but it only seems to let me have 6 siblings no matter what angle I put in or even make the distance bigger to make more room:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap, concept color=black, text=white, level 1 concept/.append style={level distance=200,sibling angle=10}]
  \node[concept] {Metaverse}[clockwise from=0]
    child[concept color=green!50!black] {
      node[concept] {Programmes}
      [clockwise from=60]
      child { node[concept] {Commis chef} }
      child { node[concept] {ESOL} }
      child { node[concept] {Retrofit} }
      child { node[concept] {Construction} }
      child { node[concept] {Early years}}
      child { node[concept] {Electrical Engineering}}
      child { node[concept] {EV design point}}
      child { node[concept] {Health and social}}
      child { node[concept] {Nursing}}
      child { node[concept] {Plumbing and social}}
      child { node[concept] {Renewable energy}}
      child { node[concept] {Welding and fabication}}
      child { node[concept] {Unassigned programmes}}
    }
    child[concept color=blue] {
      node[concept] {Functional skills}
      [clockwise from=0]
      child { node[concept] {level} }
      child { node[concept] {access} }
    }
    child[concept color=red] { node[concept] {Concept} }
    child[concept color=orange] { node[concept] {Use} };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Sorry my first mindmap and I don't know what I'm doing and I cant see in the manual that it has a limit.

the sibling angle specified for the level 1 concepts is too narrow.

I did some experimenting, and found that the styles can be defined per level:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap, concept color=black, text=white,%
                   level 1 concept/.append style={level distance=200,sibling angle=40},%
                   level 2 concept/.append style={level distance=100,sibling angle=25}]
  \node[concept] {Metaverse}[clockwise from=0]
    child[concept color=green!50!black] {
      node[concept] {Programmes}[clockwise from=150]
      child { node[concept] {Commis chef} }
      child { node[concept] {ESOL} }
      child { node[concept] {Retrofit} }
      child { node[concept] {Construction} }
      child { node[concept] {Early years}}
      child { node[concept] {Electrical Engineering}}
      child { node[concept] {EV design point}}
      child { node[concept] {Health and social}}
      child { node[concept] {Nursing}}
      child { node[concept] {Plumbing and social}}
      child { node[concept] {Renewable energy}}
      child { node[concept] {Welding and fabication}}
      child { node[concept] {Unassigned programmes}}
    }
    child[concept color=blue] {
      node[concept] {Functional skills}
      [clockwise from=0]
      child { node[concept] {level} }
      child { node[concept] {access} }
      child { node[concept] {bccess} }
      child { node[concept] {cccess} }
      child { node[concept] {dccess} }
      child { node[concept] {eccess} }
      child { node[concept] {fccess} }
      child { node[concept] {gccess} }
    }
    child[concept color=red] { node[concept] {Concept} }
    child[concept color=orange] { node[concept] {Use} };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

For testing I've added a few more blue bubbles.
It's pretty easy to run out of paper though.

Experimenting is great!

when you play with the angles...

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap, concept color=black, text=white]
  \node[concept] {Metaverse}[clockwise from=0]
    child[concept color=green!50!black, level distance=200, sibling angle=27] {
      node[concept] {Programmes}
      [clockwise from=90]
      child { node[concept] {Commis chef} }
      child { node[concept] {ESOL} }
      child { node[concept] {Retrofit} }
      child { node[concept] {Construction} }
      child { node[concept] {Early years}}
      child { node[concept] {Electrical Engineering}}
      child { node[concept] {EV design point}}
      child { node[concept] {Health and social}}
      child { node[concept] {Nursing}}
      child { node[concept] {Plumbing and social}}
      child { node[concept] {Renewable energy}}
      child { node[concept] {Welding and fabrication}}
      child { node[concept] {Unassigned programmes}}
    }
    child[concept color=blue, level distance=150, sibling angle=90] {
      node[concept] {Functional skills}
      [clockwise from=-90]
      child { node[concept] {level} }
      child { node[concept] {access} }
    }
    child[concept color=red, level distance=150, sibling angle=90] { node[concept] {Concept} }
    child[concept color=orange, level distance=150, sibling angle=90] { node[concept] {Use} };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

